# converting MySQL datetime to milliseconds javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm writing a `PHP/JavaScript` automation tool. In that tool, it's important to save the time which time was run, so we can use it to create a `Google Finance` style of stock chart, which allows us to follow the performance pattern of those tests.
The data coming in is basic: `date`, a `DateTime` and `average`, the average time for each test.

```
id    Date                  Average

351   2013-04-22 15:57:49   154.3
347   2013-04-22 13:58:54   157
344   2013-04-22 12:00:06   444.7
340   2013-04-22 10:01:30   445.3
333   2013-04-22 08:02:24   263
```

The data come in as a `JSON`, after being queried from the `MySQL` database. However, the `API` I'm using requires data as:

```
[
  [1145836800000,440.50],
  [1145923200000,427.16],
  [1146009600000,425.97],
  [1146096000000,420.03],
  [1146182400000,417.94]
]
```

I'm using [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-shapes/gray) to produce such charts. How can I convert the `Datetime` strings to milliseconds in JavaScript?
*** I'm using `PHP` in the backend.

Comment: What backend are you using? PHP?

Comment: @Jonast92 I'm using `PHP` in the backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to do the conversion in the back-end.

Fetch the timestamp from the database, and instead of returning the selected timestamp then you should simply convert the timestamp and return it inside of the JSON.

Most of server side programming languages support a function for the converting.

You can do it like this in PHP:

```php
// selectedTimeStamp is of the form 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
$strTime = strtotime($selectedTimeStamp);
```

But if you really want to do it in the javascript..

```js
d.getTime();
```

Where d is the selected timestamp.

Example:

```js
// The selected timestamp, using a dummy value here.
var selected = "April 04, 2013 22:30:00"; 
var d = new Date(selected); 
var ms = d.getTime();
```

It's possible that you have to convert it to this format, but I think that the w3school can show you more.

You can read more on: http://w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: Bro, I do that and I get NAN. Do a console.log(ms) and see the output

Comment: Try it with the edited format I posted. You might have to convert the time. But really, just do it in the backend :) much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do this with JavaScript then try this:

```
var ms = new Date("2013-04-22 15:57:49").getTime();  // 1366660669000
```

[image]

Comment: Bro, I do that and I get `NAN`. Do a `console.log(ms)` and see the output.

Comment: @philippe not sure why it's not working for you.  Updated answer with screenshot.